# PHP time add 7 hours to it and INSERT into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, datetime

I am trying to add 7 hours to a date entered on a HTML form through PHP.
The screenshot of the form is below.

```
$varOpenMT4Time = $_POST['openmt4time'];
date_add($varOpenMT4Time,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
```

This is the code I currently have on the php page and the MySQL INSERT statement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (employeeName,orderNumber,system,symbol,type,volume,price,openmt4time,openlocaltime) 
        VALUES ('$session_user','$_POST[orderNumber]','$_POST[system]','$_POST[symbol]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[volume]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[openmt4time]','$varOpenMT4Time ')";
```

[image]

Comment: what is and what did **date_add()**? what is the error? what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using Date function

```
$varOpenMT4Time = $_POST['openmt4time'];// Eg:-'06/02/1991 11:30'; /// use your format
$date = new DateTime($varOpenMT4Time);
$date->modify("+7 hours");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i"); // mysql friendly way, used to insert in database
```

Comment: How would I add the $date->format("Y-m-d H:i"); to the mysql insert statement.

Comment: store it in a variable : `$new_date = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i");` then  add it into insert query

Answer (score 2):

```
$currDate='2015-07-20';
$date = new DateTime($currDate);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT7H'));
$featureDate=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:sO");
```

You can use $featureDate directly into SQL Query..

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime(date('H:i:s').'7 hours'));
```

use this code i hope it's working..